# Making DIV table cell fill a parent table cell for jquery slideshows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been searching for a while but I can't seem to figure out a way to get a table cell div to fill another table cell div.

Here's the gist of the situation. I'm trying to adapt a [Jquery slideshow](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-slideshow) to display 4 separate slideshows in 4 responsive columns. I'm using percentage to determine width and heights of each table cell.

The difficulty is that, while I've managed to get the columns themselves to work, the slideshow plugin requires new div table cells within those cells to call upon. At least, that's how it's done in the examples provided. Here's the relevant code I have thus far.

```
 <body>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="gallery">
       <div id="drawc">
         <div class="draws1"></div>
       </div><div id="graphicc">
         <div class="graphics1"></div>
       </div><div id="pixelc">
         <div class="pixels1"></div>
       </div><div id="animationc">
         <div class="animations1"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>

body {
background-image: url('http://server.dewcraft.com/doodleplex/storage/themes/KokenTheme/inc/BG.jpg');
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-attachment: fixed;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.container {
text-align: center;
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 70%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
.gallery {
text-align: center;
display: table-row;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 70%;
}
#drawc {
display: table-cell;
height: 70%;
width: 25%;
padding: 0;
}
.draws1 {
background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8624213/Fijian_Crested_Iguana_Perth_Zoo_SMC_Sept_2005.jpg) no-repeat center center local; 
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: table-cell;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

The divs to be loaded will all be div class "draw#" with subsequent numbers put within the #drawc div.

You can see the site as it is now [here.](http://ronochromatic.com)

Truth be told I don't really understand jquery much. It looks pretty complicated, but I was hoping I could just copypaste the codes into my HTML and CSS files and it'll work, once I figure out this div sizing issue.

If anyone can help me understand how to make the slideshow work that would be helpful, but if that's too involved I understand.

Thanks in advance for anyone who tries to help.

Comment: try another slideshow plugin, there are lots of responsive ones nowadays

Comment: Ok, found another one, though I'm having new issues with it, though I think it's workable if I can just figure out the right way to format it.